# Active Record, Polymorphic Has Many Through with STI

Tags: activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance, sti

I'm having some trouble with a Polymorphic Has Many Through association with STI. Let me explain what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have a Contract. A Contract can have many Companies as parties to the agreement, namely, a Contract can have more than one Licensor (the party granting rights in the Contract) and more than one Licensee (the party receiving rights under the Contract). Both Licensors and Licensees are Companies that can be parties of more than one Contract.

So far I have the following code:

```
#contract.rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :relationships
  has_many :licensors, through: :relationships, source: :party, source_type: "Licensor"
  has_many :licensees, through: :relationships, source: :party, source_type: "Licensee"
end

#relationship.rb
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :party, polymorphic: true
end

#company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships, as: :party, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contracts, through: :relationships
end

#licensor.rb
class Licensor < Company
end

#licensee.rb
class Licensee < Company
end
```

I think I'm very close on getting this to work. So far, the above code allows me to create a new contract and add licensors and licensees, as follows:

```
c = Contract.new(nickname:"Test Contract")
lor = c.licensors.new(name:"The Licensor Company")
lee = c.licensees.new(name:"Some Licensee Company")
c.save
```

Then the following will work:

```
c.licensors # results in...
Licensor Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "companies"."id" = "relationships"."party_id" WHERE "relationships"."contract_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."party_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["contract_id", 1], ["party_type", "Licensor"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Licensor id: 1, name: "The Licensor Company", created_at: "2018-02-14 19:46:19", updated_at: "2018-02-14 19:46:19">]>

c.licensees # results in...
Licensee Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "companies"."id" = "relationships"."party_id" WHERE "relationships"."contract_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."party_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["contract_id", 1], ["party_type", "Licensee"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Licensee id: 2, name: "Some Licensee Company", created_at: "2018-02-14 19:46:19", updated_at: "2018-02-14 19:46:19">]>
```

So the Licensor and Licensee are being correctly created and their party_type is being correctly set.

Unfortunately, what doesn't work is the following:

```
lor = Licensor.first
lor.contracts # which results in...
Contract Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "contracts"."id" = "relationships"."contract_id" WHERE "relationships"."party_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."party_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["party_id", 1], ["party_type", "Company"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

As you can see, I'm unable to query a list of Contracts for a specific Licensor or Licensee. It appears this is because my current setup results in query with a party_type of "Company". I assume this is because both Licensor and Licensee inherit from Company.

Is there a way to set the party_type in the Has Many Through association in the Licensor or Licensee models?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: no expert, but maybe setting the inverse on the belongs_to side can help here? "The automatic guessing of the inverse association uses a heuristic based on the name of the class, so it may not work for all associations, especially the ones with non-standard names." - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rewhere`.  In `Company` define `relationships` with an association scope like this:

```
has_many :relationships, ->(x) { rewhere(party_type: x.class.name) }, as: :party, dependent: :destroy
```

You can see the `party_type` of `Licensor` being queried in the join:

```
>> l = Licensor.first
  Licensor Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."type" IN ('Licensor') ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Licensor id: 1, name: "The Licensor Company", type: "Licensor", created_at: "2018-02-23 00:38:13", updated_at: "2018-02-23 00:38:13">
>> l.contracts
  Contract Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "contracts".* FROM "contracts" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "contracts"."id" = "relationships"."contract_id" WHERE "relationships"."party_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."party_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["party_id", 1], ["party_type", "Licensor"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Contract id: 1, name: "Test Contract", created_at: "2018-02-23 00:38:13", updated_at: "2018-02-23 00:38:13">]>
```